# Copy an Array to The Middle of an Other Array

Tags: c++, arrays, copy

Let's say I have two char arrays:

```
char a[] = "0123456789";
char b[] = "abcde";
```

Now I need to copy some of 'b' into the middle of 'a', so I will have this result:

```
0123abcd89
```

So I tried using either std::copy, or std:copy_n

```
std::copy(b , b+4, a+4); // or

std::copy_n(b , 4, a+4);
```

Both which give an error, while simply using them with the start of the 'a' array works fine:

```
std::copy(b , b+4, a); // or

std::copy_n(b , 4, a);
```

In the past I always just used a loop to do this kind of stuff, but now I need a way to do this as efficiently as possible. Is there a better way than using a loop?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: actually, #3 is an answer to this I think :) (in the sense that I'd stop there at least).

Comment: @lorro I [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09f8000b1de16c81) what's claimed in the post.

Comment: @Dietmar Yes I realized that when testing at coliru, though there's an error claimed in the OP?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't see an error with the original code. It also works OK for me so I don't know what the question is about...

Comment: @Kaaf: what compiler are you using? Also, can you try using `std::copy(b , b + 4, +a + 4)` (not the extra `+` in front of `a`). It seems we can't reproduce the problem: can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Ok, this is very weird, so I am using vs2015, when I run this in debug mode, it gives me errors, but in release mode, it compiles fine. In debug, it gives me several errors, the first one has this: " To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS". So it is one of these "optional" warnings, first time to see an error of this king, well first time I realized it at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was a debug mode only -unsafe function call- error in VS, it compiles fine in release mode and other compilers.